# 'Package' object has no attribute 'level' when inheriting logging.Logger

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a custom class called `Package` that has logging capabilities.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('console')

class Package(logging.Logger):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self,exc_type,exc_val,exc_tb):
        pass
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        pass

with Package() as p:
    p.error('test')
```

For some reason I get this error message when I use any of the logging functions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    p.error('test')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1334, in error
    if self.isEnabledFor(ERROR):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1548, in isEnabledFor
    return level >= self.getEffectiveLevel()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1537, in getEffectiveLevel
    if logger.level:
AttributeError: 'Package' object has no attribute 'level'
```

Comment: Why does your `__init__` do literally nothing?

Comment: If I don't have `__init__` python doesn't seem to recognize it is a module and I get a slightly different error (Typerror instead of AttributeError). This isn't the full code its the minimum verifable code that produces the error I'm getting in my full code (which sometimes uses `__init__` aswell )

Comment: The error comes from trying to execute the code `p.info('test')`, which does not appear in the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry I changed it from p.info to p.error because p.info doesn't actually write anything to console. Still the same error though. I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code.

1. To correctly initialize the base class `logger.Logger` you need to call it's `__init__()` method. For example:

   ```
   class Package(logging.Logger):
       def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
           logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. The base `logging.Logger` class requires a name, so you need to give your logging object a name. For example:

   ```
   with Package("test") as p:
       p.error("test")
   ```

So, the code snippet above would look something like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('console')

class Package(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self,exc_type,exc_val,exc_tb):
        pass

with Package("test") as p:
    p.error('test')
```

If you run this you will still get an error since you haven't defined a handler for your logging class yet, however you can find more info about logging handlers here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers.